# What did mathematicians study as an undergraduate/graduate before modern mathematics such as modern algebra and analysis?

Tags: soft-question, math-history, education, big-list, mathematicians

I am curious as to what mathematicians such as Leibnitz and Gauss and the Bernoulli's studied when they were students in university.  I find it fascinating how we are taught calculus and abstract algebra in a few semesters, usually as late teenagers or early 20s, yet in the 17th and 18th century these were brand new concepts that certainly took a long time to develop by mature mathematicians. By the time we get to college, we already know elementary algebra and many major ideas that were developed before calculus. So, before abstract algebra and analysis and topology and PDEs..., what were our great mathematical ancestors studying in school?

Comment: I bet Gauss just rediscovered all the important theorems of number theory by himself during his years at university.

Comment: Surely they studied Euclidean geometry.

Comment: @Krijn: I bet he did that when he was in pre-school. :-P

Comment: "By the time we get to college, we already know ... pretty much everything that was developed before calculus." Who is this "we"?

Comment: "By the time we get to college, we already know elementary algebra and pretty much everything that was developed before calculus." - This is an entirely naive view of mathematics.

Comment: Perhaps I should've written something along the lines of 'every major contribution'. Edited.

Comment: @Johann: That is not the major problem with the claim. For example, a great deal of combinatorics, matrix theory, and solid geometry was known before Newton. Almost none of that makes it to elementary education (at least in the American system)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To give one example: Cauchy. I choose to discuss him because he straddled the threshold of "modern analysis."

He entered the *lycée* ("high school") *École Centrale du Panthéon* in 1802, studying humanities. Then, in 1805 he entered the *École Polytechnique* at age 15.

The "core" mathematics curriculum at the *École Polytechnique* was:

> **Analysis instruction**: the *Cours d'Analyse Algébrique* by Garnier and
>   the *[Traité Élémentaire de Calcul Différentiel et Intégral](http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k6213792j)* by
>   Lacroix;
>
> **Mechanics instruction**: the *Traité de Mécanique*, using the methods of Prony and edited by Francoeur and the *Plan Raisonne du Cours de Prony*;
>
> **Descriptive geometry instruction**: the *[Géométrie Descriptive](http://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=nyp.33433057782298;view=1up;seq=13)* by Monge;
>
> **Applied analysis instruction**: the *Feuilles d'Analyse Appliquée a la
>   Géométrie* by Monge and the *Application de l’Algèbre a la Géométrie*
>   by Monge and Hachette.

(Belhoste, Bruno. *[Augustin-Louis Cauchy: A Biography](http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4612-2996-4)*. New York: Springer-Verlag, 1991. pp. 7-10. Appendix II is Cauchy's outlines of his analysis courses he taught at the *École Polytechnique* from 1816-1819.

See [the distribution of courses at the École Polytechnique when Cauchy was a student there](http://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=hvd.32044079809943;view=1up;seq=400).)

Also, according to the *[Oxford English Dictionary](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/7046)*, "[analysis](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/7046)" originally meant

> the proving of a proposition by resolution into simpler propositions already proved or admitted (*obs.*); (later) algebra (now *hist.*). Now: the branch of mathematics concerned with the rigorous treatment of functions and the use of limits, continuity, and the operations of calculus.